# NetSuite - Custom Inline HTML Field to show date Field formatted

Tags: sql, netsuite

I am trying to change the format of a datefield that I am displaying in an inline HTML Field.  but it throws an error when I try and use the TO_CHAR() method.

`TO_CHAR({custrecord_bb_project.custentity_hoi_expiration_date},'MM/DD/YYYY')`

gives me an ERROR: Invalid Expression

```
'<span style="color: #6f6f6f; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase;">Expiration Notice </span><br>' ||
CASE 
    WHEN {custrecord_bb_project_package_action} = 'PTO Approved'
    THEN '<span class="input" style="font-weight:normal; ">HOI Expires: ' || TO_CHAR({custrecord_bb_project.custentity_hoi_expiration_date},'MM/DD/YYYY') ||'</span>'
    ELSE ''
END
```

Works, but does not format the date.

My only guess is that it is an issue with the single quotes and the inline HTML.  but just have not been able to crack it.

Comment: In the example you posted, the `TO_CHAR` function in the `CASE` statement does not contain the format string, so the SQL server will just return the default format.  Does this explain it?

Comment: I updated my code in the original post.  I had removed the formatting because the date/time stamp would come through and was needed by the team.